# Pegar texto del porta papeles desde un form de c# hasta una aplicación de tercero

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Buenas, esta imagen espero que pueda a ayudar a lo que quiero lograr, donde en el reconocedor de voz solo con decir escribe pega lo que hayas dicho en la otra aplicacion.

[image: introducir texto a una aplicación de tercero]

He cambiado la formulación de la pregunta, en si, teniendo mi aplicación y una aplicación de tercero sea bloc de nota, word o un navegador como google chrome donde con tan solo presionar un botón pueda copiar algún texto sea el de porta papeles o algún otro string, y pegarlo en el textbox de una aplicacion de tercero como en la barra de navegacion del navegador, o en las paginas de word.

Comment: Hola. podrias ser mucho mas claro en lo que necesitas? tomas los datos del portapapeles, eso lo has solucionado? muestranos el codigo. Y despues quieres pegarlo donde? es muy diferente pegarlo en el bloc de notas, cuando esta abierto que como un archivo nuevo. y mas diferente tratar de pegarlo en otra app cualquiera.

Comment: bueno, lo de obtener el porta papeles ya obtengo lo que se a copiado ahora quiero que en una aplicacion abiarta digamos bloc de notas con solo precionar un boton se pege los datos en el tectbox de la aplicacion o en la zona de escritura del bloc de nota, (no crear ni abrir un .txt sino pegarlo en un bloc de notas abierto)

Comment: vuelvo a preguntar.. tengo nociones de como se hace, pero nunca lo hice. hay que ubicar el proceso y hacer una especie de send message a ese proceso para que acepte los datos del portapapeles, que no se si es posible. solo al bloc de notas?? aclara eso en la pregunta...

Comment: Ahora si! mucho mejor, se entiende mejor lo que necesitas.. si has probado algo, agrégalo también!

Comment: A esta pregunta le faltan detalles y es amplia: ¿Qué pasa si tienes múltiples blocs de notas/aplicación de destino abiertas? ¿Qué has intentado y con qué errores/dificultades te estás encontrando? Te recomiendo que leas [ask] en el centro de ayuda y que crees un [mcve] si es posible.